# get position of the first "{" before my current Cursor In Text Editor ( Java - RCP)

Tags: java, regex, eclipse-plugin, stringtokenizer, split

```
IDocument doc = editor.getDocumentProvider().getDocument(editor.getEditorInput());
int CursorPosition = 
textSel.getOffeset();
String TextBeforeCursor = 
doc.get(0,cursorPosition);
```

I want get Position of "{" before my cursor and then i'll replace 0 by accPositionBeforCursor 
How can i get position of the first { befor cursorPosition ? 
All Thanks

Comment: what is the input, what should the output be?

Comment: Well you can just search the document, but if you want to avoid false hits in comments and strings you probably need to use the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) code